# Json Output Play framework / Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

Creating Json is easy with play framework / scala.
here is an example about it ,

```
 import play.api.libs.json.Json

val json: JsValue = Json.parse("""
{ 
  "user": {
    "name" : "toto",
    "age" : 25,
    "email" : "toto@jmail.com",
    "isAlive" : true,
    "friend" : {
      "name" : "tata",
      "age" : 20,
      "email" : "tata@coldmail.com"
    }
  } 
}
""")
```

For more information and source : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you just want an array, not an object:

```
Json.arr(
  Json.obj(
    "id" -> "node37",
    "name" -> 3.7,
    "data" -> Json.obj(),
    "children" -> Json.arr()
  ),
  Json.obj(
    "id" -> "node38",
    "name" -> 3.8,
    "data" -> Json.obj(),
    "children" -> Json.arr()
  )
)
```

Which gives

```
 [{
      "id": "node37",
      "name": "3.7",
      "data": {},
      "children":[]
 },
 {
      "id": "node38",
      "name": "3.8",
      "data": {},
      "children":[]
 }]
```

Comment: This is an improvement , i also need to have this "id"and other fields without "" .

Comment: That is not correct JSON. Why do you need to generate invalid JSON?

Comment: Because i will use this library in order to implement a graph.Like here [link](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html)

Comment: I don't see why it is required... Don't you use `JSON.parse()` in the browser? Still it is possible to declare such an object in JS: `var foo = {"id": 1234}`

Comment: I don't know how can i use that , can you give me an example about that the syntax of what i want is obvious then what i am going to do with Json.Parse() ?

Comment: You receive the JSON as text, name it `jsonresponse` (for example `var jsonresponse = "[{\"id\": 123}]"`). Then you parse it with `JSON.parse(jsonresponse)` which returns a plain javascript array...

Comment: okey in that case it gives me an error like :recursive value json needs type                     var jsonresponse= Json.arr(
  Json.obj(
    "id" -> "node37",
    "name" -> 3.7,
    "data" -> Json.obj(),
    "children" -> Json.arr()
  ),
  Json.obj(
    "id" -> "node38",
    "name" -> 3.8,
    "data" -> Json.obj(),
    "children" -> Json.arr()
  )
)
val Json=Json.parse(jsonresponse)

Comment: what i need actually finding a way to remove   quotation marks from the json output.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` is to be used client-side ;)